# How can I add a custom field to log entries with log4j?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I need to add a custom field to log entries, like this:

```
[KEYWORD] [Date/Time] [LEVEL] [Message]
```

The **KEYWORD** can be present or not in the log entry depending on a boolean value I pass to the log methods:

```
logger.info("message here", true) // Keyword is present
logger.error("message here", false) // keyword is not in log entry
```

Is this possible using the machinery provided by log4j, without changing its code?

p.s. I know I can add the custom field in the message part. I am wondering how hard it is if I insist on placing the field at the beginning of the log entry.

Comment: `logger.info("message here", true)` - Where do you think this method is going to come from?

Answer (score -2):

I think you can write your implementation of logger by extending log4j